# Twin, cousin, sexy, ... primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Twin, cousin, and sexy primes are of the forms $(p,p+2)$, $(p,p+4)$, $(p,p+6)$ respectively, for $p$ a prime.
The Wikipedia [article on cousin primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_prime) says that,
"It follows from the first Hardy–Littlewood conjecture that cousin primes have the same asymptotic density as twin primes," but the analogous [article on sexy primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime) does not make a similar claim.

> **Q1**. Are the sexy primes expected to have the same density as twin primes?
>
> **Q2**. Is it conjectured that there are an infinite number of cousin and sexy prime
>   pairs?
>
> **Q3**. Have prime pairs of the form $(p,p+2k)$ been studied for $k>3$?
>   If so, what are the conjectures?

Thanks for information or pointers!

Comment: There is a very general conjecture in the theory of prime numbers -- Schinzel's Hypothesis H (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel's_hypothesis_H) which covers your Q2.

Comment: @Douglas: Exactly the type of info I seek. Thanks!

Comment: In regards to **Q2.** it has been proven that there are infinitely many primes with a gap of $6$. The gap was originally $63,374,611$ (rounded off to $70,000,000$) and then brought down over the years, especially by Terence Tao and the open Polymath project he launched in $2013$. Since every pair of sexy primes differ by $6$, then there are infinitely many sexy primes. The question still remains for cousin primes and twin primes.

Comment: @user477343 Can you give a reference for this? To Wikipedia's knowledge, the Polymath-reduction to 6 depends on the Elliott–Halberstam conjecture, which is not proven up to now. Your comment seems to imply, that there are indeed infinitely many sexy primes.

Comment: @Babelfish There is a booked called *Things to Make and Do in the Fourth Dimension* (2014) written by Australian stand-up comedian and mathematician (and member of the [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoxcjq-8xIDTYp3uz647V5A) crew) who talked about the polymath project in his book (Chapter Seven: *Prime Time*, page $152$). He wrote that as of $20$ July, $2013$, the brought the gap from just under "[$70$ Million](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkMXdShDdtY)" to $5,414$. I then saw on wikipedia that they proved there are infinitely many primes with a gap of $246$.

Comment: @Babelfish I soon realised the book was outdated, and then Yitang Zhang proved that there exists an $n\leqslant 246$ such that there are infinitely many primes gaps of $n$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574781/infinitely-many-pairs-of-sexy-primes)). I then stumbled upon wikipedia, that ***if*** the [Riemann Hypothesis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6c6uIyieoo) is true, then there are infinitely many primes with a gap of $6$. This, although a conjecture, is *highly* likely to be true; but the *only* evidence not agreeing is "the largest sexy prime" thus far (May 2009).

Comment: @Babelfish you can also go [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880738/is-there-any-conjecture-that-has-been-proved-to-be-solvable-provable-but-whose-d) for the "$n\leqslant 246$" part (particularly [@GerryMyerson's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880738/is-there-any-conjecture-that-has-been-proved-to-be-solvable-provable-but-whose-d/2881223#2881223)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q1**. Are the sexy primes expected to have the same density as twin
>   primes?

No, they are expected to have twice the density of the twin primes. This is because $(p,p+6)$ forms a different residue class than $(p,p+2)$ (and $(p,p+4)$). The Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuple conjecture provides a way to estimate the amount of primes $p$ below a positive integer $x$ such that $p+6$ is also prime. If we denote this number by $\pi(x)_{(p,p+6)}$, we have:

$$
\pi(x)_{(p,p+6)} \sim 4 \prod_{p>=3} \frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2} \int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t^2}.
$$

> **Q2**. Is it conjectured that there are an infinite number of cousin and sexy prime pairs?

Yes.

> **Q3**. Have prime pairs of the form $(p,p+2k)$ been studied for $k>3$? If so, what are the conjectures?

Yes. In particular, the already mentioned Hardy-Littlewood conjecture provides a way to calculate an asymptotic density for such constellations, *if* indeed there are an infinite number.

Answer (score 13):

Sorry for the necropost, but I've only just now read this question. Both Q1 and Q3 are also considered in the first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture. In essence, the conjecture (also known as the k-Tuple conjecture) gives the density of such things as twin primes, cousin primes, and the like.

To be more precise, it considers pieces of the form $ p, p + a_1, p + a_1 + a_2, ..., p + a_1 + ... + a_k$ where infinitely many primes will be hit. So not only do pairs of the form (p, p + 2k) have their own conjecture, but so do triples such as (p, p + 2, p + 4) and such.

The actual conjecture can be found here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-TupleConjecture.html

Comment: Please don't refer to it as the "first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture"; this is an oft-repeated mistake -- if anything, that refers to Goldbach's conjecture.  The conjecture that p and p + 2k are simultaneously prime infinitely often with a specified density is their Conjecture B.  The broader conjecture you mention is not in their famous 1923 paper (nor in any of the other joint Hardy-Littlewood papers I've read), though it does follow from the Schinzel-Sierpinski paper or that of Bateman & Horn.

Comment: @Charles: Let's just call a spade a spade $$$$ :)

Comment: Triple primes $(p,p+2,p+4)$ do not have their own conjecture since there is just one example: $(3,5,7)$.

Answer (score 5):

Modulo $30$:  Twins: $11/13$, $17/19$, $29/31$.  Cousins: $7/11$, $13/17$, $19/23$.  Sexy: $1/7$, $7/13$, $11/17$, $13/19$, $17/23$, $23/29$.  Each of the $8$ co-primes modulo $30$ are primes that beget an infinite number of primes, e.g., of form $7 + 30k$.  If nothing untoward occurs in the netherlands, cousins and twins are equally dense, but half the density of sexy primes.