# Infinitely many pairs of sexy primes?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I recently discovered what sexy primes are, primes of the form (p,p+6), where p is a prime. I have no background in number theory so pardon me if the answer is trivial.

So are there infinitely many pairs of them? Is there any reading material on them? Or a proof or counter example I can study? Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you just recently discovered what sexy primes are, don't think everybody else knows, but include the definition, please.

Comment: Why the motion to close this question? I am requesting references for it? Is that not a valid enough question?

Comment: Voters of closing this question, please suggest improvements? I'm not sure why the question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that there is *at least one* difference smaller than [seventy million](https://youtu.be/vkMXdShDdtY) (this result may have been improved since) which gives infinitely many pairs of primes. Whether $6$ is one of them we don't know.

Comment: Is there a book or article on the asymptotic density of sexy primes you could recommend?

Comment: @Hades All I know about the subject is more or less summarised in that video. Sorry.

Comment: See the article Prime Gap in Wikipedia, especially the section Upper Bounds. The value 70 million (proved in 2013) is the first known bound but has since been improved considerably..

Answer (score 2):

There is lot of information about sexy primes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime. Even the largest sexy prime pair is stated as $11,593$ digits. But unfortunately nothing is said about finiteness of the pairs, triplets, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how knowing the largest pair tells us anything about their finiteness? Every year, we find a larger and larger prime, but we know there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: What I mean was, when whether there are finitely or infinitely many pairs is not proved, knowing the largest pair has nothing to do with determining the finiteness. But your example was really nice, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Hades Such questions don't have useful answers. If you don't know an unsolved problem, don't complain if people are pointing that out.

Comment: Sorry. I don't mean to be rude. But stating information from Wikipedia doesn't help. I am looking for mathematical texts.

Comment: @Hades But you are rude. If you emphasize your non-existing background in number theory, how is anybody to know that Wikipedia isn't too much of a challenge for you, let alone articles about number theory?

Comment: Apologies. I will delete the comment. Sorry @AsBk3997.

Comment: Well, as I told you, I appreciated the example you have given, I had no idea about the "sexy primes" so I also did some research on it and shared what I found. Whether it is an easy to find source or not is not my concern, one could miss some of the sources, although they are known well, and there is no way I could have known which sources you found about the topic. If you don't find some answers useful, you simply can add the sources that you have found while asking the question @Hades.

Comment: I understand. Wikipedia is the first go-to reference one uses. I was looking for something a lot more rigorous. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

See [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture), which asserts that for any even $n$ there are infinitely many prime $p$ for which $p + n$ is prime, i.e., there are infinitely many *prime gaps* of length $n$.

The strongest unconditional result in this direction is due to a Polymath wiki after Yitang Zhang's big breakthrough: there is some even $n \leq 246$ for which there are infinitely many prime gaps of length $n$.